# How do I insert data while maintaining a relationship between entities using prisma?

Tags: nestjs, prisma

Before the question, I am sorry for the part where grammar can be strange, my language is not English.

Recently, I am working on a new project through Nestjs & Prisma.
How do I put my data in while maintaining the relationship between User Entities and Post Entities?

The codes below are defined entity scheme and the ones I tried.

```
model Post {
  content String
  id      Int    @default(autoincrement()) @id
  title   String
  userId  Int?
  user    User?  @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
}

model User {
  email String?
  id    Int     @default(autoincrement()) @id
  name  String?
  posts Post[]
}
```

1. 

```js
@Injectable()
export class PostService {
    constructor(private readonly prismaService: PrismaService) {}
    
    async create(userId: number, postCreateDto: PostCreateDto) {
       const {title, content} = postCreateDto;
       return await this.prismaService.post.create({
           data: {
                title: title,
                content: content,
                userId: userId
            }
         })
     }
}
```

2. 

```js
@Injectable()
            export class PostService{
                constructor(private readonly prismaService: PrismaService) {}
            
                async create(userId: number, postCreateDto: PostCreateDto) {
                    const post = await this.prismaService.post.create(postCreateDto);
            
                    return await this.prismaService.post.upsert(
                        {where: {id: post.id},
                            update: {userId: +userId}})
                }
        }
```

this is dto that i used

```
export interface PostCreateDto {
    title: string,
    content: string,
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you are asking how you are generally able to work with relations in the Prisma Client. The problem is that you are trying to write to the `userId` field directly. This is something that is currently not possible. Instead you have to use the field `user` and one of the special relation operations for nested writes. Those are documented [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-client/relation-queries#nested-writes).

So i recommend to change your Prisma client calls to the following. Instead of providing the `userId` field directly those examples are using the `connect` operation which is used to connect to another record. This will then update the `userId` field under the hood in the database.

```js
// for 1.
return await this.prismaService.post.create({
    data: {
        title: title,
        content: content,
        user: {
            connect: {
                id: userId
            }
        }
    }
})

// for 2.
return await this.prismaService.post.upsert(
    {
        where: { id: post.id },
        update: {
            user: {
                connect: {
                    id: userId
                }
            }
        }
    })
```